# Set org-duration-units for org-mode scheduling

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to set `org-duration-units` that's used by `org-mode` effort estimates for formatting times in 8 hour days instead of 24 hours days.

I'm in no way an emacs and lisp expert, currently learning as I go along. I tried this in my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(use-package org
  :mode (("\\.org$" . org-mode))
  :ensure org-plus-contrib
  :custom
   (org-duration-units   `(("min" . 1)
   ("h" . 60)
   ("d" . ,(* 60 8))
   ("w" . ,(* 60 8 5))
   ("m" . ,(* 60 8 5 4))
   ("y" . ,(* 60 8 5 4 11)))
  )
  :config
    (setq org-clock-persist 'history)
    (org-clock-persistence-insinuate)
    (setq org-clock-idle-time 15)
    (setq org-duration-format 'h:mm)

 ;; also tried to set it in the config block instead to be executed after load
 ;; (setq org-duration-units   `(("min" . 1)
 ;;                               ("h" . 60)
 ;;                               ("d" . ,(* 60 8))
 ;;                               ("w" . ,(* 60 8 5))
 ;;                               ("m" . ,(* 60 8 5 4))
 ;;                               ("y" . ,(* 60 8 5 4 11))))
 ;;  (org-duration-set-regexps)

    )
```

I then try to use `org-duration-from-minutes` in some code displaying a table to convert a duration to some nicely formatted times with 8 hour days. Here is a minimum org-mode example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp

;; six month of 4 weeks of 5 days of 8 hours per day (120 days of 8 hours)
;; expecting 6m 00:00
;; or 40 days of 24 hours

(print (org-duration-from-minutes 57600 ))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 40d 0:00
```

It shows it in 24h days format. When I run

```
(setq org-duration-units `(("min" . 1) ("h" . 60) ("d" . ,(* 60 8)) ("w" . ,(* 60 8 5)) ("m" . ,(* 60 8 5 4)) ("y" . ,(* 60 8 5 4 10))) )
```

Then it shows it as `120d 0:00`

How do I get emacs to set `org-duration-units` at startup ? It looks like it's either not set or overridden in the way I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs version: 26.1
org-version: 9.1.13

You are customizing for the wrong package.

Use package `org-duration` instead of `org` for `org-duration-units`:

```el
(use-package org
  :mode (("\\.org$" . org-mode))
  :ensure org-plus-contrib
  :config
    (setq org-clock-persist 'history)
    (org-clock-persistence-insinuate)
    (setq org-clock-idle-time 15)
    (setq org-duration-format 'h:mm))

(use-package org-duration
  :config
  (setq org-duration-units   `(("min" . 1)
   ("h" . 60)
   ("d" . ,(* 60 8))
   ("w" . ,(* 60 8 5))
   ("m" . ,(* 60 8 5 4))
   ("y" . ,(* 60 8 5 4 11))))
  (org-duration-set-regexps))
```

It does not help if you execute code after loading `org` since `org-duration` is loaded per `autoload` afterwards.

---

Using `:custom` gives pitingly wrong results if the `use-package` form is executed only once.

The reason is that `customize-set-variable` is executed before `org-duration` is loaded. (The order of loading the package and executing the `:custom` forms is not defined in the [use-page](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package). Even so I consider that almost a bug.)

But, you can use `customize-set-variable` in `:config` to get the wanted effect:

```el
(use-package org-duration
    :config
    (customize-set-variable
     'org-duration-units
     `(("min" . 1)
       ("h" . 60)
       ("d" . ,(* 60 8))
       ("w" . ,(* 60 8 5))
       ("m" . ,(* 60 8 5 4))
       ("y" . ,(* 60 8 5 4 11)))))
```

Comment: Thanks @Tobias, I didn't realise it was in another package. 
Could it also be set with the  `:custom` command ? From what I understand, this might be a more canonical way which automatically calls `org-duration-set-regexps`?

Comment: @nab I added a remark on `:custom`.